# Reading excel sheets from a file and binding them to form a single dataframe

Tags: r, readxl

I have the following two functions which reads excel sheets, does some data cleaning and binds these sheets together.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
read <- function(Path, Sheet){
  df <- read_excel(path = Path, sheet = Sheet, 
             skip = 24,
             na = '-')[-2, ]  %>%
    mutate(name = Sheet) %>%
    rename_all(~str_replace_all(., "\\s+", ""))
  
  return(df)
}

sheets <- function(number){
  if(number == 1){
    Sheets <- c("A", "B")
  } else if(number == 2){
    Sheets <- c("C","D")
  } else{
    warning("sheet number can only be 1 or 2")
  }
  s1<-read(path="Data/file1",Sheet=Sheets[1])
  s2<-read(path="Data/file1",Sheet=Sheets[2])
  return(rbind(s1,s2))
}
```

The functions work fine, but I want to update the 'sheets()' function so that it binds any number of sheets together (instead of just assuming a fixed number (2) sheets as I've done above. I am thinking of using a for loop for this but is there a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `excel_sheets` to get all the sheets in the excel and combine them  together with `map_df`.

```
sheets <- function(path){
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
  purrr::map_df(sheets, read, Path = path)
}

result <- sheets('Data/file1')
```

Comment: Thanks for that! But I only want to read in some of the sheets from the excel file, not all of them

Comment: You can replace `sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)` with `sheets <- c('A', 'B', 'C', ..)` include the sheet names that you want to read.